# Assigning more than one word to a node in a graph using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I want to create a graph for a sentence by assigning words to the nodes based on the tag assigned to each word. If the word is a proper noun, it will be assigned to the subject list, if the word is a noun it will be assigned to the object list and if the word is a verb it will be assigned to the verb list.

I'm using Python 2.7 in Jupyter Notebook.

```py
sentence_list=['Arun Mehta drinks milk']
tag_list={'Arun':'NP','Mehta':'NP','drinks':'VF','milk':'NN'}
tag_list_keys = tag_list.keys()

subject_list=[]
object_list=[]
verb_list=[]

def classify(item):

    if item in tag_list_keys:

        if tag_list[item] == 'NP': subject_list.append(item)
        if tag_list[item] == 'NN': object_list.append(item)
        if tag_list[item] == 'VF': verb_list.append(item)


def extract(item):

    item_split = item.split(' ')
    map(classify, item_split)


map(extract, sentence_list)

print('SUBJECT:',subject_list)
print('OBJECT',object_list)                 
print('VERB',verb_list)


%matplotlib notebook

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.Graph()

for i in range(3):
    G.add_node(object_list[i])
    G.add_node(verb_list[i])
    G.add_node(subject_list[i])

    G.add_edge(verb_list[i],object_list[i])
    G.add_edge(subject_list[i],verb_list[i])

nx.draw(G, with_labels= True)

plt.show()
```

Expected output should have three nodes consisting of 'Arun Mehta' as one node, 'drinks' in the second node and 'milk' in the third node. Can somebody please suggest what needs to be done in order to  get two or more words in one node?

Answer (score 0):

In your `extract`method you are splitting at every space. This is the reason why you only have single words inside your graph. You may want to check if two adjacent words are subjects and join them again.

To answer your basic question, networkx supports

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('Arun Mehta')
print(G.nodes)
```

Output: `['Arun Mehta']`

I have modified your code to join two adjacent subjects and modified it a little bit to work with python 3

```
sentence_list=['Arun Mehta drinks milk']
tag_list={'Arun':'NP','Mehta':'NP','drinks':'VF','milk':'NN'}
tag_list_keys = tag_list.keys()

subject_list=[]
object_list=[]
verb_list=[]
list_by_tag = {'NP':subject_list,'NN':object_list, 'VF':verb_list}

def classify(items):

    last_tag = tag_list[items[0]]
    complete_item = items[0]

    for item in items[1:]:

        current_tag = tag_list[item]

        if current_tag == last_tag:
            complete_item = item + " " + complete_item
        else:
            # append last item
            list_by_tag[last_tag].append(complete_item)
            # save current item and tag
            complete_item = item
            last_tag = current_tag

    # care about last element of the list
    list_by_tag[last_tag].append(complete_item)


def extract(item):

    item_split = item.split(' ')
    classify(item_split)


list(map(extract, sentence_list))

print('SUBJECT:',subject_list)
print('OBJECT',object_list)                 
print('VERB',verb_list)


%matplotlib notebook

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.Graph()

for i in range(1):
    G.add_node(object_list[i])
    G.add_node(verb_list[i])
    G.add_node(subject_list[i])

    G.add_edge(verb_list[i],object_list[i])
    G.add_edge(subject_list[i],verb_list[i])

nx.draw(G, with_labels= True)

plt.show()
```